# How to scanf a variable to subtract int variable of struct after that printf the subtracted number

Tags: c, struct

I would like to improve a code to buy more than 1 product at a time by scanf the amount.
so I create a variable to store the amount of buying then subtract the product in shop by that amount but it can't work. The printf result of the quantity that left in shop and amount of buying in cart is showing an arbitrary number. How do I solve this?

```
struct Product
{
     int id;
     int qty;
     int buy;
     int left;
};

FILE *fp,*fp1;
    struct Product t2;

void purchaseProduct();
struct Product findProduct (int id);
void updateProduct (int id, int qty);

char fproduct[]={"product.dat"};

int found = 0, ch1 = 1, id;
```

```
void purchaseProduct()
{
    while(1)
    {
        displayAllProduct();
        if (ch1 == 1)
        {
            fp = fopen(fbill, "ab");   //write the purchase information in fbill file
            printf("\n\n Enter the product ID and amount Purchase");
            scanf("%d", &id);
            scanf("%d", &t2.buy);
            t2 = findProduct(id);
            fwrite(&t1,sizeof(t1),1,fp);
        }
        fflush(stdin);
        break;
    }
}
```

```
struct Product findProduct (int id)
{
    fp = fopen(fproduct, "rb");
    while(1)
    {
        fread(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fp);
        //break at the end of file
        if(t2.id = id)
        {
            updateProduct( id , t2.qty-t2.buy );    //how to substract by a multiple
            break;
        }
    }
    //close file 
return t2; }
```

```
void updateProduct (int id, int qty)
{
    fp = fopen(fproduct, "rb");
    fp1 = fopen("temp.dat", "wb");
    while(1)
    {
        fread(&t, sizeof(t),1,fp);
        // break at the end of file fproduct
        if (t2.id == id)
        {
            found = 1;
            t2.qty = qty;
            fwrite(&t,sizeof(t),1,fp1);
        }
        else
        {
            fwrite(&t, sizeof(t),1,fp1);
        } } //close both file 
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] which demonstrates your problem. Define the input to be used for provoking the problem. State the desired output. Show the output you get. Explain the difference. Report on the debugging efforts you made ( e.g. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ ).

Comment: Atrilivs, Review `scanf("%d", &t2.buy);  t2 = findProduct(id);`  Why set `t2.buy` to some value and then overwrite it in the next statement?

Answer (score 1):

this can be one of the solutions

```
printf("\n\n Enter the product ID: ");
scanf("%d", &id);
printf("\n\n Enter the amount of buy: ");
scanf("%d", &t.buy);
```

but read man scanf well so that you can modify it according to your needs

Comment: I do change the scanf but the printf display is sitll the arbitrary number                                ``` ID  Quantity
1  100

what I expect after buy out 3

ID  Quantity
1  97

but this display instead

ID  Quantity
1  778328516
```

Comment: ALWAYS check the return value from scanf to see if it sucessfully parsed what you expect it to.